# How convert a column from a multi-dimensional array into a comma-separated string?

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, implode

Is it possible to explode an array like this.

```
$arr=array();
$arr[0]['id']='123';
$arr[0]['otherdatas']=
$arr[1]['id']='234';
$arr[1]['otherdatas']=
$arr[2]['id']='567';
echo "string: ".explode($arr[]['id'],',');
```

and end up with this?

```
string: 123,234,567
```

Doing the above results in:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in /data/www/test.php on line 8

How can I go about this without doing something like...

```
function getIDs(){
    foreach($arr as $val){
        if($string){$string.=',';}
        $string.=$arr['id'];
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Is there some better way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you're trying to *`implode`* the strings, not `explode`. Secondly, no, there's no syntax shortcut for expressing the operation *"join all `id` keys in all sub arrays together"*. You can do it very concisely like this though:

```
echo join(',', array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $arr));
```

Comment: Concise. @Steve, do keep in mind that anonymous functions, such as in this example, only work in PHP 5.3+

Comment: For PHP 5.2-: `join(',', array_map(create_function('$i', 'return $i["id"];'), $arr))`.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP5.5 and up, you can call [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to isolate a single column of data in your multi-dimensional array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rLCS7))

```
$arr=array();
$arr[0]['id']='123';
$arr[0]['otherdatas']='';
$arr[1]['id']='234';
$arr[1]['otherdatas']='';
$arr[2]['id']='567';

echo implode(',',array_column($arr,'id'));
```

Output:

```
123,234,567
```

Answer (score -1):

no, it`s impossible.

```
function myExplode ($data=array(),$row='id',$delimiter=','){
  $result='';
  foreach ($data as $item) $result.=($data[$row])?$delimiter.$data[$row]:'';
  return $result;
}
```